# IPython %edit command: Temporary text document it opens is read only

Tags: python, command-line, installation, ipython

I just installed [IPython](http://ipython.org), and am beginning with Python.

I'm trying to use the [`%edit`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tips.html?highlight=edit#lightweight-version-control) command. It opens my text editor (TextPad, Windows 7), but the document is read only. I can't type anything. I unchecked the read-only flag, but got a "sharing violation" when attempting to save it.

When I close the document, this is the response:

```
In [11]: %ed
IPython will make a temporary file named: C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Local\Temp\ipython_edit_y_ckd5hu\ipython_edit_8ard11v3.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
Out[11]: ''

In [12]
```

Am I understanding the `%edit` command properly? You type commands, save, and they're run in IPython when you close the editor. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is the only thing I could find related to this problem, and it's unresolved: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2007-March/002681.html

Thank you.

Comment: That might mean that we're not closing the file before calling your editor. On Windows, only one program can have a file open at a time.

Comment: Yep, we've got an issue open for it: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5946

Comment: Thanks. Added a comment to the issue.

Comment: Workaround: Create a temporary file (such as `temp.py`), and then, instead of `%edit`, use `%edit temp.py`.

Comment: Actually, at least when using TextPad on Windows, you don't need to create the file at all. `%edit newfilename.py` works. TextPad opens and prompts you to create a new file with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment as an answer.

This was a bug in IPython, already known about as [issue 5946](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5946). When we created a temporary file, we left it open, and on Windows, only one program can have a file open at a time. This has now been fixed, and it should work when IPython 2.2 and IPython 3.0 are released.